# Docker Compose + Django CLI commands: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have a django + vue project built using django cookie cutter with docker. Because I've done this with docker, after starting my containers, I can't use the normal `python manage.py command` command. I instead get this error message `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable`. I have searched everywhere to figure out how to fix this but I can't find anyone with a fix for this.

So my question is:

1. Is there a fix for the DATABASE_URL error I am getting? -- Steps to reproduce are follow these cookie cutter django with docker [instructions](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developing-locally-docker.html#getting-up-and-running-locally-with-docker) and try to run `python manage.py migrate`.

**EDIT:**

I should note that I have tried to export the db url and that works temporarily. Other issues arise because some how multiple env variables are not being read correctly. If you follow the setup of the django + docker and export db url you will see what I mean.

Comment: @iklinac Exporting DB_URL is not the fix. That is for the dockerless project. Reproduce using the Docker + Django proj and you will see that even if you export the db url, there are other issues that arise. Also links without explanation are not helpful in the slightest. Let alone the link to the very site I've included in the post. Please try to be more helpful next time.

Comment: so you simply need to add DATABASE_URL in your settings.py or environment documentation is there for you to understand what DATABASE_URL is
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/

Comment: @iklinac I have already included it in my postgres env

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have local settings as env variable set

so you have to run it as

```
python manage.py migrate --settings=config.settings.local
```

or add it to env as

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'config.settings.local'
```

Comment: I tried both things you have suggested. Neither worked. I thought cookie cutter set the local.yml such that if I build my container using that, it should automatically be using the correct settings. Also the database_url is only referenced in the base.py so I'm not sure if explicitly choosing the local settings does much.